Reflecting point across bisector of acute angle leads to perpendicular elsewhere

Exercise. Let $\angle BAC$ be an acute angle. In the interior of $\angle BAC$ there is a point $P$ whose projections onto the sides $AB$ and $AC$ are precicely $B$ and $C$.
Draw the bisector of the angle $\angle BAC$. Reflect the point $P$ across the bisector, denoting its reflection by $P'$.
Q: Why are $AP'$ and $BC$ necessarily perpendicular?

In the following picture, the dashed line is the bisector of $\angle BAC$. The intersection of interest, of $AP'$ and $BC$, is denoted by $J$ in red. The letter $H$ stands for the the intersection of $BC$ with the bisector, and $G$ for the intersection of $BC$ with $AP$, in case these come in handy.

The situation when $P$ itself lies on the bisector is clear, so you may assume it lies strictly on either side of bisector.

Hints are quite welcome, especially if I am missing something fairly obvious.


Hint: Can you see AO is the angle bisector of BAC as well as PAP'?

@DS Ah. Yes, triangles AOP and AOP' are congruent by SAS. Then let measures of angles PAO and P'AO be "a"; measures of BAP, CAP' be "b". Denote by K the intersection of PC and AP'. Angle chasing shows that AKC=JKC is 90 – b, and that BPC is 180 – 2a – 2b. Assuming that ABPC is a convex quadrilateral (I should verify this), then by opposite angle supplementarity is cyclic. In particular, the circumcircle will circumcise subtriangles(angles) ACB and APB with common side AB. This AB is also a chord, so these angles have equal measure, 90 – b. Then KCJ is with measure b. Since JKC = 90 – b, J= 90.

Yeah, this was what I was hinting at, I encourage you to answer your own question.

@DS Thanks. I took up your offer with a hopefully final edit a moment ago.


Thank you to D S for the hint.

By assumption of OP body text, $P$ is not on the bisector $AO$ of $\angle BAC$. Thus $\triangle AOP$ and $\triangle AOP'$ are right triangles with common side $AO$. By SAS and construction of $P'$ from $P$ via reflection, these triangles are congruent, whence $\measuredangle OAP = \measuredangle OAP' =: \alpha$. Also by OP's text, the intersection of $AP'$ and $BC$ is denoted by $\color{red}{J}$.
Denote what is left over of $\angle BAC$ on either side by
$\measuredangle BAP = \measuredangle \color{orange}{C}\color{blue}{A}\color{darkgrey}{P'} =: \beta$, remembering that $AO$ was a bisector.

We have the angle measure $\measuredangle \color{blue}{A}\color{goldenrod}{P}\color{blue}{B} = 90^{\circ} - \beta$, being part of the right triangle $\triangle ABP$. Similarly, $\measuredangle APC = 90^{\circ} - 2 \alpha - \beta$ from right triangle $\triangle ACP$. These are right triangles by virtue of $B, C$ being projections of the interior point $P$ by definition.

A quadrilateral $ABPC$ is worth contructing. This quadrilateral is non-intersecting: by $\angle BAC$ being an acute angle with $P$ in its interior, only $BP$ and $PC$ could conceivable intersect elsewhere than at the common endpoint. But then $B$, $P$, $C$ would be collinear, with $BPC$ intersecting both $AB$ and $AC$ at right angles. So lines $AB$ and $AC$ should be parallel or coincide, both of which are impossible since the angle $\angle CAB$ was acute.
The quadrilateral $ABPC$ is convex because it is non-intersecting and its opposite sides are semiparallel. Namely, the open segment $PC$ cannot intersect the line $AB$ because $PC$ lies in the interior of the angle $\angle BAC$. Similarly, the open line segment $BP$ cannot intersect the line $AC$.
As a convex quadrilateral, it will be concyclic if opposite angles are supplementary, which they are: $\measuredangle A + \measuredangle P = (2 \alpha + 2 \beta) + (180^{\circ} - 2 \alpha - 2 \beta) = 180^{\circ} $, $\measuredangle B + \measuredangle C = 90^{\circ} + 90^{\circ} = 180^{\circ}$.
So the quadrilateral $ABPC$ is concyclic. In other words, a circle will go through all points $A$, $B$, $P$, $C$.

The triangles $\triangle \color{blue}{A}\color{goldenrod}{P}\color{blue}{B}$ and $\triangle \color{blue}{A}\color{orange}{C}\color{blue}{B}$ are subtriangles of the concyclic quadrilateral $\color{blue}{A}\color{blue}{B}\color{goldenrod}{P}\color{orange}{C}$, so their vertices lie on the same circle. They have the chord $\color{blue}{AB}$ in common. As inscribed angles subtending the joint intercepted arc $\overparen{\color{blue}{AB}}$, it follows that $90^{\circ} - \beta = \measuredangle \color{blue}{A}\color{goldenrod}{P}\color{blue}{B} = \measuredangle \color{blue}{A}\color{orange}{C}\color{blue}{B}$.

The points $A$, $C$, $\color{red}{J}$ cannot be collinear, otherwise $P'$ would also be collinear with them, contradicting the fact that $P'$ lies in the interior. So the triangle $\color{springgreen}{\triangle} AC\color{red}{J}$ exists.

Finally, $\measuredangle \color{blue}{A}\color{orange}{C}\color{blue}{B} = \color{springgreen}{\measuredangle} AC\color{red}{J}$ and $\measuredangle \color{orange}{C}\color{blue}{A}\color{darkgrey}{P'} = \color{springgreen}{\measuredangle} CA\color{red}{J}$, since by the definition of $\color{red}{J}$ the underlying angles are the same. Therefore $\color{springgreen}{\measuredangle} AC\color{red}{J} = 90^{\circ} - \beta$ and $\color{springgreen}{\measuredangle} CA\color{red}{J} = \beta$.
The leftover from $\color{springgreen}{\triangle} AC\color{red}{J}$ is $\color{springgreen}{\measuredangle}\color{red}{J} = 180^{\circ} - \beta - (90^{\circ} - \beta) = \color{red}{90^{\circ}}$.


This finishes the proof. $\blacksquare$

Nice use of colors (+1)!
